# Use of Adjective + のも

Tags: particle-の, adjectives, particle-も, nominalization

> さらに冬になれば雪が積もって交通の便が悪いし、暮らすにはいささか苦労が多い**のも**難点だ

I'm familiar with Vのは　→　Vのも　for multiple nominalized items, but this use of it has me stumped.

"Because of the transportation issues after the snow piles up, the slight hardships: (consists of) many issues"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm familiar with Vのは

Then, you understand 暮らすにはいささか苦労が多い **のは** 難点だ.

I think you are familiar with **も** which means *also* or *too* in the sentences as:
「町には人**が**多い。車**も**多い。」
*"There are a lot of people, also a lot of cars in the town."*

「町に人が多い **のは** 当然だ。車が多い **のも** 当然だ。」
 *"It is natural that there are a lot of people in the town. It is also natural that there are a lot of cars in the town."* .

Now, I think you understand the **のも** in the original sentence.

Answer (score 4):

も in this context simply means "also". も can replace some particles such as は, を (i.e., のは → のも). And this の is a nominalizer which turns the preceding clause into a noun.

The nominalized part is a bit long: "冬になれば雪が積もって交通の便が悪いし、暮らすにはいささか苦労が多い". 暮らすには苦労が多い literally means "hardship is abundant to live".

> さらに[冬になれば雪が積もって交通の便が悪いし、暮らすにはいささか苦労が多い]の**も**難点だ。
>   Yet **another** problem is [that snow prevents us from getting around in winter and there are various (other) troubles to live a life].

Comment: How does the sentence indicate "there are various (other) troubles"?. Is it not : "Yet another problem is [snow preventing us from getting around in winter causes  various troubles to live a life]." ?